# codeigniter redirect to language with location as default link

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, multilingual

currently working on codeigniter multiple language website. My site name is www.abcd.com which is calling default controller. Need to redirect www.abcd.com/en/location as default link, when user will change the language it will redirect like www.abcd.com/fr/location . What will be the bast way to do this, any help will highly appreciated

Comment: best way is to define the url in routes.php

Answer (score 0):

I use sessions like this

application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller']    = "default_controller/select_home";
//if make a generic page public example
$route['public/(:any)']         = 'public/public/page_render/$1';
```

default_controller.php

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->router =& load_class('Router', 'core');

    $this->_set_lang_language($this->get_language());
}

public function select_home( $page = 'index' ){
    redirect(base_url($page), 'refresh');
}

public function get_language(){
    if( is_null($this->session->userdata('language')) || ! $this->session->userdata('language')){
        $_language      = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    }
    else{
        $_language      = $this->session->userdata('language');
    }

    return $_language;
}

private function _set_lang_language( $language = '' ){
    switch($language){
        case 'en':
                                $new    = 'english';
                                break;
        case 'es':
        default:
                                $new    = 'spanish';
                                break;
    }

    $this->lang->load('calendar', $new);
    $this->lang->load('date', $new);
    $this->lang->load('db', $new);
    $this->lang->load('email', $new);
    $this->lang->load('form_validation', $new);
    $this->lang->load('ftp', $new);
    $this->lang->load('imglib', $new);
    $this->lang->load('number', $new);
    $this->lang->load('profiler', $new);
    $this->lang->load('unit_test', $new);
    $this->lang->load('upload', $new);
}

public function set_language( $language ){
    $this->session->set_userdata('language', $language);

    $this->_set_lang_language();
}
```

application/public/public.php

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function page_render( $page ){
    //you can change your lang with parser or with deferents views as you want
    $data = array(...);

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view($page, $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this with routes, i always recommend to use a separate controller class with name **MY_Controller** inside **application/core** that extends the default **CI_Controller**.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
    }
}
```

Then in your controller (let's say Example_controller), you have to extend the **MY_Controller** and add in the constructor the functionality you want.

```
class Example_controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

What you can do inside MY_Controller for your needs? Well, you can check the

> $language = $this->uri->segment(2); *//careful, the number depends on your project*

and apply your functionality in if statements for **$language**.

You have to combine with session in order to check if user has already chosen his language.